# Bounding at Newton Divided Difference Formula

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, numerical-calculus

Let $a=x_0,x_1,...,x_n=b$ are $n+1$ points which are equally spaced in $[a,b]$. The distance between consecutive terms is $h= \frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x \in [a,b]$

Show that $ \biggr|\prod_{i=}^n (x-x_i) \biggr| \leq \frac{h^{n+1}.n!}{4} $

I have written

$ \biggr|\prod_{i=}^n (x-x_i) \biggr| =  \biggr| (x-x_0)(x-x_0-h)(x-x_0-2h)...(x-x_0-nh) \biggr|$

I know it is so easy but I couldn’t see in no way. I think I have written something unnecessary. Thanks for any help..

Comment: $x$ is any real number? or $x\in [a,b]$?

Comment: @RicardoLargaespada sorry I’ve forgotten to write it. $\in [a,b]$

Answer (score 0):

Argue that the maximal error occurs in the boundary intervals. Set $x=sh$. Then
$$\prod_{k=0}^n|x-x_k|=h^{n+1}|s(1-s)|\cdot|2-s|\cdots|n-s|$$
and the bound should be obvious.

More generally, for $x=mh+s$, $m=0,...,n$, you get
$$h^{n+1}|m+1-(1-s)|⋯|2-(1-s)|⋅|s(1-s)|⋅|2-s|⋯|n-m-s|\le \frac14h^{n+1}(m+1)!(n-m)!$$

---

Take the next term into the maximum calculation, thus maximizing $s(1-s)(2-s)$ and find the maximum for $s\in [0,\frac32]$ at the interval ends or the root of
$$
0=3s^2-6s+2\iff s=1-\frac1{\sqrt3}
$$
so that the bound can be decreased to 
$$
h^{n+1}\frac{n!}{3\sqrt3}.
$$

Comment: How can I get $\frac{h^{n+1}n!}{4}$ with your writtens? I’m sorry I could not understand

Comment: With the easy estimates $k-s\le k$ and $s(1-s)=\frac14(1-(2s-1)^2$.