# Interpolation Error Bounds

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I am currently trying to prove bounds for some polynomial interpolants (Lagrange to be precise) and am having problems proving the following:

$$
\left|\left| f(x) - p_n(x) \right|\right|_{\infty} \leq C_nh^{n+1}\left| \left|f^{(n+1)}(\xi_x)\right| \right|_{\infty}
$$

where $f(x)$ is the function to be appoximated, $p_n(x)$ is the interpolant of degree $n$, $h$ is the uniformly spaced *time step* $\left( =\frac{b-a}{n} \right)$ and $\xi_x\in [a,b]$ (The function is to be approximated between the values $a$ and $b$).

I have taken the following for granted:

$$
f(x)-p_n(x) = \frac{w_{n}(x)}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(\xi_x)
$$

where

$$
w_n(x) = \prod^{n}_{k=0}(x-x_k)
$$

Now in an effort to compute the bounds:

\begin{align}
\left|\left| f(x)-p_n(x) \right|\right|_{\infty} &= \max_{x\in[a,b]} \left| f(x) - p_n(x)\right|\\
&= \max_{x\in[a,b]}\left|\frac{w_{n}(x)}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(\xi_x)\right|\\
&\leq \max_{x\in[a,b]}\left|\frac{w_{n}(x)}{(n+1)!}\right|\max_{\xi_x\in[a,b]}f^{(n+1)}(\xi_x)
\end{align}

However, looking through *An Introduction to Numerical Methods and Analysis (Epperson, 2002)*, the following steps have been made

$$
\max_{x\in[a,b]}\left|\frac{w_{n}(x)}{(n+1)!}\right| = C_nh^{n+1}
$$

due to uniform spacing, and

$$
C_1=\frac{1}{8}, \ \ C_2=\frac{1}{9\sqrt{3}}, \ \  C_3=\frac{1}{24}, 
$$

I do not understand this final step and in particular where these values came from. I would appreciate any hints to point me towards the right direction.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3042386/115115) to a similar question give enough hints?